# Registering javascript in aspx calling web.config

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to make my app more flexible. I'm using a third party component (rich text editor). On the page the component is used, I need to register some javascript. At the moment, this is done so :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Resources/Xinha/my_config.js"></script>
```

I tried some options, like this one but none worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Xinha.PathToPackage"]%>/XinhaCore.js"></script>
```

Are there any suggestions on what I am missing or isn't this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is definitely possible but it can really create some havoc w/ ASP.NET's ajax implementation - ASP.NET Ajax doesn't like "<%=%>" in the header...

You can try either of these approaches from the code behind for something a little safer:

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, this.GetType(), "scriptFromConfig", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myScriptUrl"]);
```

OR

```
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("scriptFromConfig", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myScriptUrl"]);
```

UPDATE:

Per the recommendation that you not use relative pathing, I fully agree.  If you want to have a path that works throughout your site but is referenced from the web.config, make it a virtual path:

```
<add key="myScript" value="~/scripts/someScript.js"/>
```

Then in your code:

```
string scriptPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myScript"]);
```

Then use scriptPath in the `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude` or `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude` call.

Comment: I'm not working with AJAX as far as I know. And these lines, those come in the pageload?

Comment: there's no way around this in aspx page itself?

Comment: @djerry - if you use <script type="text/C#" runat="server"> ... </script> you could put the same coded logic (inside a page load handler) in the presentation file, but I wouldn't recommend embedding the <%= in the page to get the value... but again, using "<%=" directly in the page is only a concern in my experience when using Ajax/update panels...

Comment: I know, i didn't mean to say or suggest it's bad practice, but we'd prefer it apsx wise

Comment: @djerry - just use your original code then?  difficulty understanding the question at this point - your code should work fine.  (assuming you've imported the System.Configuration namespace to your presentation [aspx] file).

Comment: nothing wrong with using <%= in headers or otherwise. Some people have philosophical reasons for not wanting to use it & I wouldn't want to use it in a webforms app. ClientScriptManager is the best way to register your script though as @Brian suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a site root relative path.  From MSDN:

> A site-root relative path, which is resolved against the site root.
>   Site-root relative paths are useful if you keep resources that are
>   used throughout the site, such as images or client script files, in a
>   folder that is located under the Web site root.

The line to include it would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Resources/Xinha/my_config.js"></script>
```

Comment: For 1 page, i have 3 references to that path. Let's say I'm using this component on 10 places in my app, i need to make 30 changes and that's if I don't forget one. I thought this could be done more easily.

Comment: Add the run at server property to the script tag and use a ~ simbol to make it root relative? Maybe you can add a script manager and register the script there.

Answer (score -1):

USe the following code and it will do the work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Literal l = new Literal();
            l.Text = "<script type='text/javascript' src='../../Resources/Xinha/my_config.js'></script>";
            this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(l);
        }
```